# Is a “uniformly syndetic” dynamical system weak mixing?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, topological-dynamics

Let $X$ be a compact metric space, and $\mu$ a probability measure on $X$ with $\text{supp} \ \mu = X$. Suppose $T: X \to X$ is continuous, measure preserving and *uniformly syndetic* in the sense that it satisfies the following two conditions:

i) The orbit of every point is dense in $X$.

ii) For every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists some $N_\varepsilon > 0$ such that for every $x \in X$, and $r > 0$ with $\mu(B_r (x)) > \varepsilon$, we have that the set $\{ n \in \mathbb N| \ T^{n} (x) \in B_r (x) \}$ is syndetic with gaps bounded by $N_\varepsilon$.

> Question: Does it follow that $T$ is weak mixing?

Comment: Take $|X| = 2$ with discrete topology, $T : X \to X$ any minimal homeomorphism. This seems to satisfy your conditions but it is not weak mixing (neither topologically nor measure-theoretically). But more generally, like in your other question the latter condition seems automatic.

Comment: Right, that’s true..